# passing an array into a class function from another class's constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor

Sorry for the confusing title, basically I have created two classes, one is an object, and the other being a box that contains an array of such objects. so what I want to do is create a function/constructor inside the object class that takes in an array of ints and stores them inside the box. I want to be able to call this function through the box class constructor to  initialize these objects. So ive tried something like below but it isnt working at all, since only the first value of the array gets passed through. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class object{
     string objectName;
     int values[];
public:
     void createObject(int[]);
}
class Box{
    object objects[100];
public:
    Box();
}

Box::Box (void){
    int array1[2];
    int array2[15];
    object[1].createObject(array1);
    object[2].createObject(array2);
}
Object::Object(int Values[]){
    values = Values;
}
```

Comment: `T[]` is (mostly) not a type in C++. Your field `int values[];` needs to be `int *values;` and also pass the length around, or better `std::vector<int> values;`

Comment: can you explain a bit more on passing the length around? sorry im pretty new to c++

Comment: @Flashpaper he means instead of an array, use vector because then you won't need to worry about allocating a set size.

Comment: Unlike arrays in other languages, you can't pass them to functions, even though the syntax suggests that you can. Don't fall for that! Instead, inside the function, all you get is a pointer, which doesn't carry any information on the size. Hence, use a vector.

Comment: Being new to C++, I suggest learning about pointers, arrays, and memory allocation.  If coding on the job, by all means, use `vector<>`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use `std::vector`. The problem with arrays is that they decay to pointers when passed as arguments to functions. As a consequence, If you want to store a private copy of the elements you are forced to use heap-allocated objects and consequently do memory management by hand (with all the pain it causes).

It is much better to rely on data members that permit applying the rule of zero.

Here's a tentative solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class object {
public:
    object(std::vector<int> const& v, std::string const& object_name): v_(v.begin(), v.end()), object_name_(object_name) {}

private:
    std::vector<int> v_;
    std::string object_name_;
};


class box {
public:
    box(std::vector<object> const& objects): objects_(objects) {};

private:
    std::vector<object> objects_;
};
```

Comment: While I'm totally behind using `vector<>`, I suggested using the raw pointers instead, for learning purposes.  Good solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you instead use a `std::vector`. Arrays don't really work well being passed to functions. When you define `Object::Object(int Values[])` you are simply passing the first element of this array by value. If you were to use vectors, the function would look like this:

```
Object::Object(std::vector<int> &Values):
    values(Values)
{
}
```

Comment: should really use the ctor's init-list, and use `std::move` instead of copying.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is in your thinking on what the array is.  In C++, all an array is, is a memory pointer.  The language allows you to pass an index into the array pointer to access whatever chunk of data lives at that index.

Whenever you pass arrays between functions or classes, **pass the array name only.**  It will be interpreted as a pointer, and won't copy any data.  When you do this, you must also pass the length of the array.

Granted, most people stick with `vector<>` because it's easier, takes care of memory leaks (mostly) and is VERY efficient.  But I like doing it myself.  It's good for you.  I would try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Object
{
    string _objectName;
    int *_values;
    int _myLength;

    Object();
    ~Object();
    void createObject(int *pValues, int arrLength);
}

class Box
{
    _Object objects[100];

    Box();
}

Box::Box(void) {
    int array1[2];
    int array2[15];
    object[1].createObject(array1, 2);
    object[2].createObject(array2, 15);
}

Object::Object() {
    _values = null_ptr;
    _myLength = 0;
}

Object::~Object() {
    delete[] _values;
}

void Object::createObject(int *pvalues, int arrLength) {
    _myLength = arrLength;
    _values = new int[_myLength];
    for(int ndx=0; ndx<arrLength; ndx++) {
        _values[ndx] = pvalues[ndx];
    }
}
```

**-CAUTION-**
I just adapted your code you provided, and added some conventions.  There are a couple places in the code where I'm not sure what the purpose is, but there you go.  This should give you a good head start.